# How to remove HTML tags from rendered text form WordPress post in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, wordpress, next.js

i'm new to Next.js
I'm trying to get blog content in my Next.js App .but I'm getting htlm tag init. how can I remove them
any help will be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';

const SingleBlog = (data) => {
    return (

        <>
            {console.log(data.data)}
            {data.data.map((e, index) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <div>
                            <h1 key={index}>{e.title.rendered}</h1>
                            <p  >{e.content.rendered}</p>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
            })}
        </>

    );
};

export default SingleBlog;
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const res = await fetch(`http://spyonmobiles.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`)
    const data = await res.json()

    if (!data) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }
    return {
        props: { data } // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: check out [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: you can also use `react-html-parser`

Comment: yes this Works for me
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: e.content.rendered }} />